# Apollo Client Queries Orchestration

Tags: apollo, apollo-client

I have multiple React components wrapped with `Query` component `react-apollo`. Each fires its query once being rendered by React.

Sometimes I would like to manage Query execution based on the result of another query. So one Query will need to wait until another has returned a result, update local state, and later fire the other queries, which input/variables is based on the first query result.

Is there a best practice for this kind of orchestration using Apollo?

Or should I manage it myself with the use of the `skip` property on the `Query` component?

Comment: You can nest queries within one another. Combined with the `loading`, `error` and `data` Query render props, you can fire the inner query once the data from the parent query is actually available.

Comment: @Jaxx I understand what you mean. My Queries are in different files, not so much aware of each other.